# Update Braintree SDK in Magento V2.1.4

Tags: magento-2.1, payment, braintree

Recently we have received the **[POTENTIAL PROCESSING IMPACT - Action Required: Update your Braintree SDK version by May 1](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/best-practices/php)** notification from Braintree. And I tried to upgrade the `braintree_php` from `3.7.0` to `3.8.0` but throwing error. For this, I have run the below commands.

```
composer require braintree/braintree_php:3.8.0
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - magento/magento2-base 2.1.4 requires braintree/braintree_php 3.7.0 -> satisfiable by braintree/braintree_php[3.7.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - magento/magento2-base 2.1.4 requires braintree/braintree_php 3.7.0 -> satisfiable by braintree/braintree_php[3.7.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - magento/magento2-base 2.1.4 requires braintree/braintree_php 3.7.0 -> satisfiable by braintree/braintree_php[3.7.0] but these conflict with your requirements or minimum-stability.
    - Installation request for magento/magento2-base (locked at 2.1.4) -> satisfiable by magento/magento2-base[2.1.4].


Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

We are using Magento V2.1.4.

Please suggest us to upgrade the **braintree_php** to save from security risk.

Comment: Have you find the solution then please share..

Comment: @Magento Yes, Please download the Braintree SDK version here and install it in your Magento. https://github.com/braintree/braintree_php/releases?after=3.14.0

Comment: After the download braintree_php library from github we have to just paste that folder in vendor/braintree?

Comment: Yes, just replace the folder.

Comment: Okay Thank you ..I will change it

Comment: Can you please answer this question https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/311856/how-to-add-tax-value-in-price-filter-magento2 @Bojjaiah